# Presto function APPROX_PERCENTILE get not exist result

Tags: presto, trino

We are using presto‘s `APPROX_PERCENTILE` to calculate quantiles, but the results are not in our data collection.

Could anyone help me with this?
Thank you!

```sql
-- test sql
SELECT APPROX_PERCENTILE(x, 0.5) FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES 44,46,156,178,198,308,317,359,368,371,392,468,495,504,509,519,526,534,566,600,617,207776,232837,251596,575799,606566,629862,690977,1247659,1274939,1410858,1475113,1606614,1705740,1764699,1802117,1935795,2388198,2471839,2495978,2646356) AS y(x));
```

Result

```
55533
```

but 55533 does not exist in the collection.

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: `SELECT node_version FROM system.runtime.nodes`  `347-50-g6369a6d`

Comment: Try updating to a more recent version. I can’t reproduce it on the latest version (356)